# the space of exterior k-forms is infinite dimensional. why?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

let Z be an n-dimensional smooth manifold with smooth (n−1)-dimensional
boundary ∂Z, representing the space of spatial variables.
Denote by $Ω^k$(Z), k = 0, 1, . . ., n, the space of exterior k-forms on Z. (Note that $Ω^0$(Z) is the space of smooth functions on Z). Clearly, $Ω^k$(Z) is
(infinite-dimensional) linear space (over $R$).

Can anyone explain me why $Ω^k$(Z) infinite dimensional? if possible intuitively. 
Thank you.

Comment: What about the vector space of continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ (or $[0,1]$)?

Comment: $\Omega^k(Z)$ is a $C^\infty(Z)$-module in an obvious way, so if you believe that $C^\infty(Z)$ is infinite dimensional then what is the problem?

Comment: @PaulSiegel: A module over an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra need not be infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $n>0$ is positive then $\Omega^k(Z)$ is pretty obviously a faithful $C^\infty(Z)$ modeule... I still don't see what the problem could be?

Comment: @PaulSiegel: Well, my answer claims that there is no problem.  But let's see what transpires.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $n > 0$; the case $n = 0$ is rather trivial (and the result is false if $Z$ is finite).

The set $\Omega^k(Z)$ of $k$ forms on a smooth manifold $Z$ is not just an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space but a module over $\Omega^0(Z)$, which is the ring of $C^{\infty}$-real valued functions on $Z$.  In fact it is a *faithful* $\Omega^0(Z)$-module, which means that if $f: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a nonzero smooth function, then there is some $k$-form $\omega$ such that $f \omega \neq 0$.  This sounds a little fancy but is almost obvious: you can check it locally (if you wanted to be formal about it, one might use a partitions of unity argument and/or talk about **fine sheaves** -- but you say you want to be informal, so let's not!).

Any faithful $\Omega^0(Z)$-module is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$: do you see why?